The $\mathbb C$-linear independence of several homogeneous distribution with different degrees

Homogeneous Distribution means a distribution $u\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfying $\langle \lambda^{-d}u,\varphi\rangle=\langle u,\lambda^n\varphi(\lambda x)\rangle$ for every $\lambda>0$. And $d$ is its degree.

Assuming $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_N\in\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^n)$ are homogeneous distribution with different degrees. Prove that they are $\mathbb C$-linear independence.
I have tried to take the distribution with the largest degree to find some contradiction. But I failed. It seems that we can take some parameter and let it tend to 0 or $\infty$ to get contradiction ...?

By your definition of homogeneous distribution, $u=0$ would also be homogeneous and then any family containing this distribution would be linearly dependent. So let's take $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_N$ to all be non-zero.
Then take $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_N \in \mathbb C$ such that $a_1u_1 + \dots a_Nu_N=0$. Let $d_i$ be the degree of homogeneity of $u_i$ and assume that $d_1 < d_2 < \dots <d_N$ which we may because the degrees are all assumed to be different. For every $\varphi \in \mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)$ we have (by plugging in $\lambda^n\varphi(\lambda x)$ into the distribution $a_1 u_1+ \dots + a_Nu_N$)
$$0=\langle a_1u_1, \lambda^n\varphi(\lambda x)\rangle + \dots + \langle a_Nu_N, \lambda^n \varphi(\lambda x)\rangle = a_1 \lambda^{-d_1} \langle u_1, \varphi\rangle + \dots + a_N \lambda^{-d_N} \langle u_N, \varphi\rangle.$$
This holds for every $\lambda >0$.
If we multiply by $\lambda^{d_N}$ and let $\lambda \to 0$, the first $N-1$ terms on the right hand side go to zero. It remains
$$0= a_N \langle u_N, \varphi\rangle$$
for every $\varphi\in \mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)$. Since $u_N \ne 0$, there is at least one function $\varphi$ such that $\langle u_N, \varphi\rangle \ne 0$, which implies $a_N=0$. Now repeat the same argument, this time multiplying by $\lambda^{d_{N-1}}$ and so on to recursively obtain $a_{N-1}=0, \dots, a_1=0$. By definition, this means that $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_N$ is linearly independent.

There may be some typo in $0=\langle a_1u_1, \lambda^n\varphi(\lambda x)\rangle + \dots + \langle a_Nu_N, \lambda^n \varphi(\lambda x)\rangle = a_1 \lambda^{-d_1} \langle u_1, \varphi(\lambda x)\rangle + \dots + a_N \lambda^{-d_N} \langle u_N, \varphi(\lambda x)\rangle$. And it seems that this formula will affect the following content.

@TaD you are right; there was a typo. But actually, this makes the following argument even easier, because $\lambda$ does not appear on the right hand side anymore.

Oh, right, it's simpler. Thanks!
